# Wordpress Custom Field group not displaying all data

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've been bugging about this issue for days now so hope to find a solution here.

I'm trying to display data coming from a Custom Field Group. Here's a sample layout of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to display 20++ of those columns. However, I'm only getting about 11 coming from this custom field group.

Here's my code for the template of the page:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Branches Page */  

get_header();

global $currentCity;

$registration_link = get_post_meta(96, 'registration_link', true);
$registration_text = get_post_meta(96, 'registration_text', true);


$thumbnail_url  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
?>
    <!-- FEATURE IMAGE
    ================================================== -->
    <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check for feature image ?>

    <section class="feature-image" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: cover;" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

    <?php } else { // fallback image ?>

    <section class="feature-image feature-image-default" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

    <?php } ?>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="primary">

            <div id="content" class="col-sm-12>

                <section class="main-content">

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop ?>

                    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'branches_locations', 'orderby'=>'post_id', 'order'=>'ASC' ) ); ?>


                    <div class="resource-row clearfix">
                        <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                        <?php
                            $resource_url = get_field('resource_url');
                            $address = get_field('address');
                            $city    = get_field('city');
                            $branch_image = get_field('branch_image');  
                            $senior_high_ready = get_field('senior_high_ready');

                        ?>

                        <div class="resource">

                            <?php 
                            if( $city <> $currentCity )
                            {
                            ?>
                                <h2>
                                    <?php echo $city; ?>
                                </h2>

                            <?php 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            ?>  
                                <h2 class="hidden-dummy-header">
                                    Blank
                                <h2>    
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>

                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                            <p><?php echo $address; ?></p>

                            <?php
                            if( $senior_high_ready == True)
                            {
                            ?>
                                <h5 class="senior_high_ready">
                                    SENIOR HIGH READY
                                </h5>

                            <?php 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            ?>  
                                <h5 class="hidden-dummy-header">
                                    Blank
                                </h5>   
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>

                            <img src="<?php echo $branch_image[url]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $branch_image[alt]; ?>">

                            <div class="register-link">

                                <a href="<?php echo $registration_link; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $registration_text; ?>
                                </a>

                            </div>

                            <?php $currentCity = $city; ?>
                        </div><!-- resource -->

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    </div><!-- resource-row -->

                </section><!-- main-content -->

            </div><!-- content -->

        </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- container -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What is causing it not to display the entire list on my custom field group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WordPress sets posts_per_page to 10, so you only get 10 at a time, unless the default is changed somewhere else in your code. You can get all posts by setting it to -1.  Like this:

```
 <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'branches_locations', 'orderby'=>'post_id', 'order'=>'ASC' ) ); ?>
```

I hope that helps!

Also, you can break that into multiple lines to improve readability, for example:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'post_type' => 'branches_locations',
 'orderby'=>'post_id',
 'order'=>'ASC' 
) ); 
?>
```

BTW, I'd refer to it as a custom post type rather than a custom field group.  (Just for future reference, as you might get better google search results if you use that term.)

Comment: thank you for the update. Yes, will use Custom Post Type next time.